# Using charAt() method on a string and bubble sort

Tags: java

I am trying to do a bubble sort on a string and I am getting the following error:

```
MyClass.java:13: error: unexpected type
                    str1.charAt(i + 1) = str1.charAt(i); 
                               ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
1 error
```

from the following code:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static boolean checkPermutation(String str1, String str2){
        char temp; 

        if(str1.length() != str2.length()){
            return false; 
        }
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i < str1.length() - 1; i++){
                if(str1.charAt(i) > str1.charAt(i + 1)){
                    temp = str1.charAt(i + 1);
                    str1.charAt(i + 1) = str1.charAt(i); 
                    //str1.charAt(i) = temp; 
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        if(checkPermutation("heello", "helelo")){
            System.out.println("comparing strings work!"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to do here `str1.charAt(i + 1) = str1.charAt(i);`? Can you describe this code? What do you think `charAt` returns: variable or value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` is an immutable type, you can't assign to characters of a string and in this particular case you can't use a method as a left-hand side of an assignment operator.

```
str.charAt(..) =
```

makes no sense since you can't assign to a value returned from a method in Java. This would work in other languages, for example C++, where you can return a `char&` from a method, but in Java you will always find something like `void setCharAt(int index, char value)` (which doesn't exist, it is just to explain the problem).

Indeed check the error:

> required: variable, found: value

You are trying to assign to a value, which is illegal, you must assign to a variable.

Just convert the `String` to a `char[]` through

```
char[] data = str.toCharArray();
data[i+1] = data[i];
```

so that you are free to do what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. One thing though, what do you mean when you say I am trying to assign to a value? Isn't str1.charAt[i+1] a variable? I guess, you would say str1.charAt[i+1] is a value. Could you please explain why it is?

Comment: `charAt(i+1)` returns a value of type `char`, so you are trying to assign to something which is already a value, take for example `int foo() { return 5; }` `foo() = 10;`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Super clear and straight to the point. Thank you :)